# Retrieve form input values using React Children as a wrapper

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to retrieve the input form data using the wrapper *save* button (Togglable component) and **not** a submit button inside a form component.

I have this **form**.

```js
const BasicDataForm = () => {
  return (
    <form>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="nameInput">Your Name: </label>
        <input placeholder="Write your name here" type="text" id="nameInput" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="ageInput">Your Age: </label>
        <input placeholder="Write your age here" type="number" id="ageInput" />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

And the **wrapper**

```js
const Togglable = ({ title, children }) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const hideWhenVisible = { display: visible ? 'none' : '' };
  const showWhenVisible = { display: visible ? '' : 'none' };

  return (
    <header>
      <h2>{title}</h2>

      <div style={hideWhenVisible}>
        <button onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>Show</button>
      </div>

      <div style={showWhenVisible}>
        <button>Save</button> {/* This button needs to retrieve all input form data from children */}
        <button onClick={() => setVisible(false)}>Close</button>

        {children}
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};
```

And the **main component**

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Form Wrapper</h1>

      <Togglable title="Basic Data Form">
        <BasicDataForm />
      </Togglable>
    </>
  );
};
```

I don't know if it's necessary to add a `useState` inside the form component. I also tried adding a new *prop* in the Togglable component that bind the `onClick` event of the *save* button to the `onSubmit` event of the form, but not work because there is no submit button inside form component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was much easier than I thought. You only need to **wrap** the entire children inside a `<form>` label and render **only** the content of the inputs. For every children a button will be added and you will manage the form outside the wrapper.

```js
const Togglable = ({ title, children, handleSubmit }) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const hideWhenVisible = { display: visible ? 'none' : '' };
  const showWhenVisible = { display: visible ? '' : 'none' };

  return (
    <header>
      <h2>{title}</h2>

      <div style={hideWhenVisible}>
        <button onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>Show</button>
      </div>

      <div style={showWhenVisible}>
        <button onClick={() => setVisible(false)}>Close</button>

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {children}
          <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};
```